# How much memory and processing does it take to convert to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, big-o

I'm working on files that will requires me to load integers into an array that is ~18million in length.

How much memory and processing time will it take to do something like

```
my_list = [123,231,90,20,...,92] #length is 18 million
new_list = np.array(my_list, type='int')
```

Would this be the computer simply creating a second array that has 18 million in length and duplicating or does numpy do something more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case "processing time" doesn't come into a great deal since it's mostly a matter of pointer lookups.  Since you tagged the post big-O, this is going to be `O(n)`.  When converting a Python `list` to a Numpy array it will reserve memory to store `len(my_list)` integers in the array--you can find out exactly how much memory this is by seeing what the default int type is on your Numpy and using the `.itemsize` attribute of the `dtype` object:

```
>>> np.dtype('int')
dtype('int64')
>>> np.dtype('int').itemsize
8
```

So this array will require `8 * len(my_list)` bytes to store on top of the memory already used by your original `my_list`.

It will then need to loop over each item in the list, look up what type of Python object it is (remember, Python `list`s can be heterogeneous--there's no way to know *a priori* that every item in the list will be convertible to an integer).  Numpy will then do its best to convert that Python object to a machine integer and store it in the list.

Depending on where these 18 million integers are coming from it may be desirable not to store them in a Python `list` in the first place, if at all possible.  But saying anything more about that would require more detail in the question.

Comment: Fair enough.  It does sound like I should just start everything off in numpy world.  Many times I see things that say "oh that is technically better but the end result makes no difference", but i think my data sets might be big enough that its worth rewriting some of the code.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: Well that does totally depend of course. And like most things it's all in how you use it. But it's a good bet. If you have any more specific questions about your code then more could be said.